# NTC wire in a replacement LI-ion battery has a different color

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, wiring, thermistor

I am replacing a battery pack in a speaker. It is a Li-ion 18650 2600 mAh 7.4 V. I got a replacement from a shop in China claiming to be local. The replacement has an NTC and three wires just as the original with the same kind of plug. But the wiring is different:

original: yellow/black/red

replacement: black/white/red

Could I just swap white and black and be done with it or is there something else that is different? Red is connected to the same pin of the plug. I don’t want to break my device.

### Update:

Here are my measurements (sorry, I don’t know how to better sketch this here)

original: b-r 7.8V / y-b 0V 10kΩ / y-r 7.8V

replacem: w-r 7.7V / b-w 0V 10kΩ / b-r 7.7V

So between y/b and b/w is the NTC but wouldn’t the measurements be the same if b and w were swapped?

[image: original]

[image: replacement]

### Update2

[image: Would it be this bit?]

Comment: "Cut the red wire". No seriously, that's not how electronics work. There are very few existing universal cable coloring standards for _anything_. You have to investigate which wire that corresponds to which signal or no can do. This question can't be answered in its current form, but maybe if you could add a couple of decent photos of the old one and the new.

Comment: Sure but I was hoping that there is some kind of semi standard that you guys would tell immediately this won’t or would work. Like usually red is + and black is GND.

Comment: Engineering doesn't involve guessing. Even if there are established color codes, I would not expect some device out of China to follow them. You have to measure it.

Comment: " Like usually red is + and black is GND. –" Yes, that is correct. At least that little bit _is_ standard.

Comment: @hk1020. Thank you for your pictures and measurements. That was very helpful.

Comment: I don’t understand why this has been closed for lack of detail or clarity. But it doesn’t matter anymore anyway as it was answered and I successfully repaired my speaker. So the question can’t have been so incomprehensible. I got very helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get a meter
2. Measure the voltage at each lead in each battery
3. Measure the resistance of each lead without a voltage in each battery

That will tell you which wire is which, regardless of wire color or position in the connector.

If the measurement in the two batteries match at the connector, then you're all set. If they don't, you'll have to remove a couple of pins from the connector in the new battery and place them in the correct positions to match the old battery.

**UPDATE** based on your update:

- Black: B-
- Red: B+
- Yellow or white: thermistor

Now, all you need to do is make the pinout in the new connector the same as the old connector:

1. Use a thin tool (a needle) to push the metal tab on the side of the connector for the black wire and pull the black wire out
2. Do the same with the white wire
3. Insert the black wire in the middle position
4. Insert the white wire in the end position.

Notes:

- Do not press the release tab too hard, or you'll deform it.
- Make damn sure that the contact on the black wire doesn't touch the contact on the red wire!

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually confirms my initial hunch. Could you help me once again and tell exactly where to push with a needle? See picture above.

Comment: You got it! Right where the blue arrow is.

Comment: Thanks again. I did it but a needle didn’t work. I used a small screwdriver. This video got me started: https://youtu.be/5wbLEwuMy3I?t=546